# Electron: Unable to load chrome extension in production build

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, electron, electron-builder

I'm trying to load a chrome extension in an electron app by,

```
const extenPath = path.join(_dir, "build/extensions/extension_name");
const response = await session.defaultSession.loadExtension(extenPath);
```

The extension loads fine in development mode but fails to in load production build by throwing following error.

```
Error: Extension directory not found: D:\path\to\app\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\src\build\extensions\extension_name
```

I can confirm that the path is valid and the folder "extensions/extension_name" is present in "app.asar\src\build".
I looked at the contents of "app.asar" to check "extensions/extension_name" presence and used "fs" module to check it's accessibility inside my "main.js" file.

Has anyone come across this issue or am I doing anything wrong here?

- os: Windows
- electron: ^13.1.2
- electron-builder: ^22.11.7
- build command: set NODE_ENV=production && electron-builder build --win

Any insights would be of great help, thanks.

Comment: Make sure manifest.json is in `extension_name` directory, not in a sub-directory.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes, the manifest.json is in the extension_name directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just managed to do this with [extraResources](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents.html#extraresources) in the package.json file, like this:

```json
"build": {
  "extraResources": [
    "./path/to/extensionFolder"
  ],
},
```

According to the documentation this will

> copy the file or directory with matching names directly into the app’s resources directory (Contents/Resources for MacOS, resources for Linux and Windows)

Then in the main.js file I imported it like this:

```js
const extensionPath = __dirname.split("app.asar")[0] + "extensionFolder";

// __dirname will aim at your app.asar file (your package source code for your application) 
// that is in the resource directory, for example:
// C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\MyElectronApp\resources\app.asar

// and your extensionFolder is next to is, at:
// C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\MyElectronApp\resources\extensionFolder

session.defaultSession.loadExtension(extensionPath);
```